# encoding issue while loading json data

Tags: python, json, encoding

How I can load this data with `json` module? Looks like I need to study some encoding lectures again, explanation would be much appriciated.

```
_json = """{"sku":"02366  20","productRef":"02366  20@1401-B1","image":"http://media.wuerth.com/stmedia/shop/348px/1337528.jpg","shortInfo":"Stahl verzinkt<br>SHR-BLA-(A2K)-M6X20","pdfCatalogPage":["http://media.wuerth.com/stmedia/shop/masterpages0000/LANG_de/03721.pdf"],"catalogSheet":"http://eshop.wuerth.de/stmedia/Blaetterkatalog/Gesamtkatalog/index.php?mode=or&searchquery=03721&hook_url=http://eshop.wuerth.de/-/","documentInfoMap":{},"cadValue":null,"showCadValue":null,"msdsInformations":[],"technicalInformation":"<table class=\"tech_table\"><tbody><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Nenndurchmesser</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>6 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Werkstoff</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Stahl</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Oberfläche</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Verzinkt</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Lochdurchmesser</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>8 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Länge</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>20 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Blattdicke</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>3 mm</p></td></tr></tbody></table>"}"""

print json.loads(_json, encoding='utf-8')

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file
```

Comment: google/searchbar + your error line = result

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to [declare your encoding](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html) at the top of the Python file, and you'll need to use a *raw* string literal, as the `\"` escapes are interpreted by Python as plain `"` characters:

```
# encoding: utf-8  
import json

_json = r"""
{"sku":"02366  20","productRef":"02366  20@1401-B1","image":"http://media.wuerth.com/stmedia/shop/348px/1337528.jpg","shortInfo":"Stahl verzinkt<br>SHR-BLA-(A2K)-M6X20","pdfCatalogPage":["http://media.wuerth.com/stmedia/shop/masterpages0000/LANG_de/03721.pdf"],"catalogSheet":"http://eshop.wuerth.de/stmedia/Blaetterkatalog/Gesamtkatalog/index.php?mode=or&searchquery=03721&hook_url=http://eshop.wuerth.de/-/","documentInfoMap":{},"cadValue":null,"showCadValue":null,"msdsInformations":[],"technicalInformation":"<table class=\"tech_table\"><tbody><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Nenndurchmesser</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>6 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Werkstoff</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Stahl</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Oberfläche</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Verzinkt</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Lochdurchmesser</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>8 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Länge</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>20 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>Blattdicke</p></td><td class=\"tech_col_left\"><p>3 mm</p></td></tr></tbody></table>"}

"""

print json.loads(_json, encoding='utf-8')
```

The above assumes that you actually did use UTF-8 as the encoding for the source file; the script then produces:

```
$ bin/python test.py 
{u'sku': u'02366  20', u'documentInfoMap': {}, u'catalogSheet': u'http://eshop.wuerth.de/stmedia/Blaetterkatalog/Gesamtkatalog/index.php?mode=or&searchquery=03721&hook_url=http://eshop.wuerth.de/-/', u'cadValue': None, u'msdsInformations': [], u'showCadValue': None, u'shortInfo': u'Stahl verzinkt<br>SHR-BLA-(A2K)-M6X20', u'technicalInformation': u'<table class="tech_table"><tbody><tr><td class="tech_col_left"><p>Nenndurchmesser</p></td><td class="tech_col_left"><p>6 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tech_col_left"><p>Werkstoff</p></td><td class="tech_col_left"><p>Stahl</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tech_col_left"><p>Oberfl\xe4che</p></td><td class="tech_col_left"><p>Verzinkt</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tech_col_left"><p>Lochdurchmesser</p></td><td class="tech_col_left"><p>8 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tech_col_left"><p>L\xe4nge</p></td><td class="tech_col_left"><p>20 mm</p></td></tr><tr><td class="tech_col_left"><p>Blattdicke</p></td><td class="tech_col_left"><p>3 mm</p></td></tr></tbody></table>', u'productRef': u'02366  20@1401-B1', u'pdfCatalogPage': [u'http://media.wuerth.com/stmedia/shop/masterpages0000/LANG_de/03721.pdf'], u'image': u'http://media.wuerth.com/stmedia/shop/348px/1337528.jpg'}
```

Comment: +1. It will work even on Python 3 where `encoding` parameter is ignored (because Unicode string literals are there by default) (if you use parens for `print`).